# How to docker-compose an image hosted in a Digital Ocean private repo?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I connected `doctl` to my account and logged into the private registry, validate it's successfully authorized, but when I try to `docker-compose up -d` an image it says that pull access is denied. What could be the reson ?

```
> doctl account get
User Email                 Team       Droplet Limit    Email Verified    User UUID                               Status
user@domain.name           My Team    25               true              aa11a5d9-1913-4f8d-b427-005fa9e11be6    active
```

Docker daemon is logged into the registry:

```
> docker login registry.digitalocean.com
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/admin/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Connection with the registry is established:

```
> doctl registry login
Logging Docker in to registry.digitalocean.com
```

My linux user is part of the docker group:

```
> groups
sudo docker
```

Docker images are present locally:

```
>docker images
REPOSITORY                                          TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
registry.digitalocean.com/project/strategy          latest    60d4796574fc   26 hours ago   1.96GB
registry.digitalocean.com/project/redis             latest    ee373138aeec   47 hours ago   177MB
```

But I'm unable to execute containers:

```
(strategy) admin@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1:/var/www/strategy$ docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/5
 ⠿ flower Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1.6s
 ⠿ celery_worker Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.6s
 ⠿ celery_beat Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1.6s
 ⠿ django Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1.5s
 ⠿ redis-4 Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1.5s
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for strategy, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: strategy
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8004:8004"
    env_file:
      - strategy/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis-4
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  redis-4:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/redis/Dockerfile
    container_name: redis-4
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6375"
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  celery_worker:
    image: strategy
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app:/strategy
    env_file:
      - strategy/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis-4
      - strategy
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  celery_beat:
    image: strategy
    command: /start-celerybeat
    volumes:
      - .:/app:/strategy
    env_file:
      - strategy/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis-4
      - strategy
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  flower:
    image: strategy
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - .:/app:/strategy
    env_file:
      - strategy/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis-4
      - strategy
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

Comment: what's your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Mihai i added the file at the end of the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the images are not correct:

```
strategy -> registry.digitalocean.com/project/strategy
redis -> registry.digitalocean.com/project/redis
...
```

If you don't specify the registry then docker assumes it's Docker Hub.